# How can we add dynamically hreflang tag in angular

Tags: angular

this code I tried it not works... please help me out

```
   const linkElt = this.renderer.createElement('link');
   this.renderer.setAttribute(linkElt, 'rel', 'alternate');
   this.renderer.setAttribute(linkElt, 'hreflang', 'ms');
   this.renderer.setAttribute(lin`enter code here`kElt, 'href', 
   "https://example.com/example1/example3/ms");
   this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.head, linkElt);
```

Comment: I did it [like this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/helpers/html-link.helper.ts), but I'm curious if there are better ways too

Comment: What do you need the hreflang for? and are you using something like SSR or Static generation?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.